# sharing web user control between various projects

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-customcontrol

Is there a way to share user controls between various projects ?

I have created user controls like login control, menu control, header control, lost password control and etc and they are all connected to sql database for data.

I would like to share these between various web site projects, it means I have same functionality and the only modifications I can do is within CSS styles.

Do I need to copy modules or is there a way to keep them as shared classes/modules and call what I need every time I need it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make an assembly/library as an extra project where you put all your user controls in. You reference this library then in different projects.

But I suggest you to make these controls then more generic, so that you do not depend on a certain database connection or any business logic.

This article might also be interesting for you:

- [Creating and Using User Control Libraries](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx)